# 000Webhost PHP $_SEND

Tags: php, html, css, web, web-hosting

My problem is the following:

I use 000webhost's free hosting service.
I have a dynamic CSS stylesheet by making it PHP and making it choose between one of a few (currently three) stylesheets and using that.
It works perfectly fine on my Apache server but not on my 000Webhost site.

It doesn't run at all, but the cookie **Is** set.

Here's some code from the three PHP pages:

1. Mainpage.php:

> ```
> <html>
>
> <head>
> <?php include("../public_html/Include/Head.php")
> ```
>
> ?>
>
> ```
> <body>
>
> <?php include("../public_html/top.php"); ?>
> ```

1. Head.php

> ```
> <?php $Send = $_COOKIE["Theme2"]; ?>
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
> ```
>
> href="../public_html/stylesheet.php?beef=" />

1. Stylesheet.php (I've put the following: CSSHERE wherever I have cut out CSS code, otherwise it would give people a hard time scrolling down!)

> ```
> <?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
>
> <?php
> if ($_GET["beef"]==1)
> {
> ?>
>
> CSSHERE
>
> <?php } 
> elseif ($_GET["beef"]==2) { ?>
>
> CSSHERE
>
> <?php } 
> elseif ($_GET["beef"]==3) { ?>
>
> CSSHERE
>
> <?php } ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the php file has to be accessible by the browser.

i.e. if your website is http://domainname.com

The stylesheet should link to http://domainname.com/stylesheet.php

Try using Chrome developer tools,
Safari developer tools,
Firefox - firebug

And check the resources/network tabs, and you should see it trying to load your script but not finding it. (My guess anyway, as generally public_html is not part of the URL.)

Comment: It loads it from the actual hosting, because it blocks reading otherwise. Although that might just be in certain cases. I'll try it out. Worked, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

go into your profile in profile go into genral setting and scroll down 
and chnge PHP virsion 7 to **version 5** .